# Making synchronous Ajax calls fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm writing a website which heavily utilises Javascript and Ajax calls to a Python web server (Flask). The problem I'm having is that the calls usually lag or freeze the page for a brief moment giving a bad user experience. This occurs when sending a `POST` request to my Python script with the following Ajax-style call:

```
var getUniversities = function() {
    var unis;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/get/universities',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'uid=1',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            unis = data;
        }
    });

    return unis;
};
```

This is the general way I'm making Ajax requests and all of them generate some form of lag for my webpage. I believe it's because I'm trying to do it synchronously, but I can't see a way to retrieve data and have it ready for processing asynchronously.

Thanks

Comment: don't do sync request and learn how to retrieve value from async request instead

Comment: No matter how *fast* you get your synchronous AJAX request, it will always be slow enough to freeze the page enough for your users to notice. That is why synchronous AJAX requests are bad practise and strongly unrecommended.

Comment: show status as "waiting", "loading" during ajax synch request, but synch is not good idea